# ArrayList<String> gives NullPointerException When adding

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, addition

I know most people make the mistake of not initializing the Arraylist and that's why they get the NullPointerException.

But in my class i have initialized my Arraylist and I still get the exception when I try to add to it.

```
protected int V;
protected int E;
protected boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix;
public int i;
public int[] num;
public ArrayList<String> edges;

public SimpleGraph(int V) {
    this.V = V;
    this.E = 0;
    this.adjacencyMatrix = new boolean[V][V];
    edges = new ArrayList<String>();
    num = new int[V];
}

public void DFS(int V) {

    num[V] = i++;
    for(int u = 0; u < getV(); u++)
    {
        if(adjacencyMatrix[V][u] == true && u != V)
        {
            if(num[u] == 0)
            {
                Integer temp = new Integer(num[u]);
                edges.add("anything");
                DFS(u);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can assume that I have correctly added to the adjacencyMatrix.

Why do I get a NullPointerException when I try adding to the Arraylist?

Comment: First of all I suggest you put more parentheses inside your "if" statement containing two tests. Even if it doesn't confuse the program (which it might) it is difficult to follow.

Comment: I am confused: You declared an ArrayList called queue, but it is never used?

Comment: where is the class variable edges defined ?

Comment: Please add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: @donfuxx Thanks for your reply, that was just a simple mistake, I use the queue for other functionalities, I do have a Arraylist of edges

Comment: We know that `num[u] == 0`, does changing the contents of the `if(num[u])...` statement to `edges.add("0:");DFS(u);` change the result?

Comment: @Kakarot I made a mistake when I copied my code, now you can see where I define it

Comment: You should post your exception provided by logcat. And please remove all that fancy logic and make a little example which only adds a string to the ArrayList. Have you ever debugged anything?

Comment: @ColinD the value of num[u] is not always 0, so I need that statement

Comment: @vanste25 I tried just adding a simple string, it still gives me the exception

Comment: @beckinho the nullpointer is coming from the block when `num[u] == 0`, inside the block, you then use `num[0]` again to create a string. The `temp.toString()+":"` is always going to generate `0:` from what I can tell. Is that wrong? I was just suggesting your inline all that logic.

Comment: Make a little compilable example, and post it in pastebin. In that way, someone could copy code and compile it in order to find a mistake.

Comment: @vanste25 Don't encourage use of pastbin. Small examples should be included in questions.

Comment: @ColinD I agree on your remark, yes that is a mistake, but that is not my problem, my problem is that even when I try to add a simple string the program gives me the exception

Comment: Post the stack trace already.

Comment: do you have another default constructor in your class ?

Comment: Im so sorry @SotiriosDelimanolis I dont know what is a stack trace :/

Comment: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: @beckinho Then Google it? One short moment of searching and you'd find out what it was. Please put a bit of effort in yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a `queue ArrayList`

```
protected ArrayList<Integer> queue;
```

But initialized a `edges ArrayList`

```
 edges = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So try to initilize the `queue ArrayList`

```
queue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Yes, but the OP adds to `edges`. So the crime is not explaining what `edges` is, not that the wrong list was constructed.

Comment: I was trying to figure out where "queue" was used and "edges" was first declared. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your class variables, you have

`protected ArrayList<Integer> queue`,

but in the `SimpleGraph()` constructor, you have

`edges = new ArrayList<String>();`

`edges` should be `queue`, or vice versa.

Additionally, `edges` should be an `ArrayList<String>` if you meant it to be the same type as `queue`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that was just a simple mistake, I use the queue for other functionalities, I do have a Arraylist of edges

Answer (score 0):

```
package test_001;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Vanste {

    protected int V = 5;
    protected static int E;
    protected static boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix;
    public static int i = 0;
    public static int[] num;
    public static ArrayList<String> edges;

    public static void SimpleGraph(int V) {
        E = 0;
        adjacencyMatrix = new boolean[V][V];
        edges = new ArrayList<String>();
        num = new int[V];
    }

    public static void DFS(int V) {

        num[V] = i++;
        for(int u = 0; u < V-1; u++)
        {   
            /*System.out.println("A1");
            if(adjacencyMatrix[V-1][u] == true && u != V-1)
            {   System.out.println("A1");
                if(num[u] == 0)
                {*/
                    Integer temp = new Integer(num[u]);
                    edges.add(temp.toString() + ":");
                    DFS(u);
                //}
            //}
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGraph(15);
        DFS(5);
        for(int i =0; i< edges.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("" + edges.get(i) + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

This example works ok. Something is wrong with your logic before adding items to the list.
Btw, you are using and incrementing variable i which is never initialized.
This statement is never true. (adjacencyMatrix[V][u] == true)
Could you please provide me a working function calls istead of mine  SimpleGraph(15) and DFS(5).